# Problems with Gear VR touchpad moving the camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, gear-vr, touchpad

I can't get my Gear VR touchpad to work - I'm just trying to move the camera position on touch. I've tried both pieces of code below:

```
public Camera cam;
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton (0)) 
    {
        cam.transform.position = new Vector3(-100f, -100f, -100f);
    }
}
```

and

```
void Start () 
{
    OVRTouchpad.Create();
    OVRTouchpad.TouchHandler += HandleTouchHandler;         
}

void HandleTouchHandler (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    OVRTouchpad.TouchArgs touchArgs = (OVRTouchpad.TouchArgs)e;
    if(touchArgs.TouchType == OVRTouchpad.TouchEvent.SingleTap)
    {
        cam.transform.position = new Vector3(-100f, -100f, -100f);
    }
}
```

My script is attached to the `OVRPlayerController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't move the VR Camera, it's the SDK that determine the *Camera* position.

In order to move your camera you can just make a new `GameObject` as a parent of your `Cam` then move the parent `GameObject` (here `ParentCamera`):

```
public GameObject ParentCamera;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton (0)) 
    {
        cam.transform.position = new Vector3(-100f, -100f, -100f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, works great! Do you know if/how (Input.GetMouseButton (1) or (Input.GetMouseButton (2) works in terms of the gear vr touchpad?

Comment: @yya can you accept this answer if it works? This is how people in stackoverflow can continue help people....

Comment: @yya you can ask another question about how it works